# AngularJs scope variable window.open

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a AngularJs Application in which I want to pass scope variable to `onclick="window.open('{{portfolio.link}}', '_system');"`

My Code :

```
<a class="item item-avatar txtShow" onclick="window.open('"{{portfolio.link}}"', '_system');" ng-repeat="portfolio in freelancer.portfolio">
  <img class="portfoliobg" src="{{portfolio.image}}">
  <h2>{{portfolio.name}}</h2>
  <p>{{portfolio.description}}</p>
  <h5>Added On :{{portfolio.adddate}}</h5>
</a>
```

Here my angularJS variable is not working and its taking it as simple text

Comment: Why do you try to write `onClick` method implementation into HTML? It makes difficult to maintenance  And why not `ng-click` (if you use Angular)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ran into a similar problem and ended up using a function in my controller to make it work.

```
    <a class="item item-avatar txtShow" ng-click="openPortfolioURL()">
  <img class="portfoliobg" src="{{portfolio.image}}">
  <h2>{{portfolio.name}}</h2>
  <p>{{portfolio.description}}</p>
  <h5>Added On :{{portfolio.adddate}}</h5>
</a>
```

Then in the controller:

```
$scope.openPortfolioURL = function() {
    try {
        var portfolioURL = $scope.portfolio.link;
        window.open(portfolioURL, '_system');
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
}
```

Credit to the [Ionic forums](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/opening-external-link-and-closing-it-at-an-event/6660/11).